# Não consigo notificar Push pelo firebase

Tags: android, android-studio, push-notification, android-notification

Tou tentando criar um aplicativo que notifique através do firebase  e pelo que pesquisei cheguei até uma parte que não saio mais queria ajuda para ver se estou fazendo certo e para corrigir meu erro.
segue meus Códigos

> MANIFEST

```
 <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.Instance_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/ic_novis" />
    <!-- Set color used with incoming notification messages. This is used when no color is set for the incoming
         notification message. See README(*LINK*) for more. -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />

</application>
```

> MyFirebaseMessagingService

```
package imperiogamerplay.deepcooee;
```

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver{
}

> MyFirebaseInstanceIDService

```
package imperiogamerplay.deepcooee;
```

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;

public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
}

Comment: vc tem q gerar o token dando override no método `onTokenRefresh`, salve isso no seu servidor e quando for mandar a notificação utilize esse token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro de faça os imports do Firebase no build.gradle (Module: app), partindo do pressuposto que já está usando o firebase no seu projeto, pois tem outros passos básicos necessários para funcionar (aqueles que o firebase te ensina a configurar quando vc cria o projeto no console):

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'
```

Será necessário esses seguintes parametros no seu manifest dentro da tag  application (junto com a declaração das activitys).

```
    <!--notificação -->
    <service
        android:name=".FCM.FCMInstanceIdService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".FCM.FCMService" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Em seguida será necessário criar as classes para o FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging)

FCMInstanceIdService.java: para gerar o token unico do aparelho. Esse grava token, é para gravar no meu servidor próprio, caso nao use apague essa classe):

```
/**
 * Criado por Leonardo Figueiredo em 20/08/2018.
 */
public class FCMInstanceIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    public static String TAG = "FirebaseLog";
    String refreshedToken;

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        super.onTokenRefresh();
        refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        gravaToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Token: " + refreshedToken);
    }

    public void gravaToken() {
        TokenModel tokenModel = new TokenModel();
        tokenModel.setTokenDevice(refreshedToken);
        tokenModel.setSo("Android");

        Call<TokenModel> call = new RetrofitConfig().getApiCandidato().gravaToken(tokenModel.getTokenDevice(), tokenModel.getSo());
        call.enqueue(new Callback<TokenModel>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<TokenModel> call, Response<TokenModel> response) {
                //sucesso
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<TokenModel> call, Throwable t) {
                //falha
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Agora será necessário a classe FCMService.java: será responsável por receber e tratar a notificação.

```
/**
 * Criado por Leonardo Figueiredo em 20/08/2018.
 */
public class FCMService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    public static String TAG = "FirebaseLog";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        Log.v(TAG, "recebeu mensagem do firebase");

        //verifica se recebeu alguma notificacao
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            String mensagem = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), PrincipalActivity.class);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, intent, 0);

            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext())
                    .setContentTitle(String.valueOf(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)))
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notificacao)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_logo_color))
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(mensagem))
                    .setContentText(mensagem)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(99, builder.build());
            Log.d(TAG, "Menssagem: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
    }
}
```

Agora basta ir no seu console do firebase, vá no menu Ampliar -> Cloud Messaging

Preencha os dados e envie e seja feliz.

OBS.:
Coloque um breakpoint na classe FCMInstanceIdService e verifique se ele gerou uma hash, esse é o id exclusivo do seu aparelho (só acontece na primeira vez que instala o App).

Antes de enviar coloque um breakpoint na classe FCMService, pois é nela que irá chegar a mensagem.